# How To Use PouchDB + SQLite For Local Storage In Your Ionic App

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2, pouchdb, phonegap

I want to use PouchDB with ionic but I am not sure whether it is as reliable as SQLite. Are there any disadvantages in using it? Is it the faster than SQLite?

Comment: https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a quote somewhere that I agree with. PouchDB is bad at everything except sync. If you don't need sync, use SQLite. It is much faster and it's easier to query. For example, on a Cordova app I built, queries on about 5000 documents took about 6 seconds to index, and 1-2 seconds to query.

If you need sync and performance isn't an issue, then PouchDB is what you want. Building your own sync system via SQLite will be a nightmare.